# When an error stops execution in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, execution

If I exec this batch:

```
begin transaction
    PRINT 'start'
    PRINT 1/0
    PRINT 'continue'
    drop table dbo.tblPrueba
    select * from dbo.tblPrueba
    PRINT 'finish'
rollback transaction
```

The ouput is this:

```
start
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Divide by zero error encountered.
continue
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid object name 'dbo.tblPrueba'.
```

I am forcing two errors:
*- the first one*: PRINT 1/0 (that generates this error:

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

) **And continue executing the batch**

*- the second one:*

```
drop table dbo.tblPrueba
select * from dbo.tblPrueba
```

That generates this error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid object name 'dbo.tblPrueba'.
```

**And stops execution of the batch**

What is the different between them? Where can I learn those that stop execution and those that doesn´t?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the first error is a divide by zero error, [this behavior depends on your ARITHABORT, ARITHIGNORE and ANSI_WARNINGS settings.](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#ANSI_WARNINGS)

From the article:

> These three SET commands give you very fine-grained control for a very
>   small set of errors. When a division by zero or an overflow occurs,
>   there are no less four choices.
>
> - No action at all, result is NULL – when ARITHIGNORE is ON.
> - Warning message, result is NULL – when all are OFF.
> - Statement-termination – when ANSI_WARNINGS is ON.
> - Batch-abortion – when ARITHABORT is ON and ANSI_WARNINGS is OFF.

As far as which errors stop execution and which ones don't, please [refer to the same article](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#whathappens).

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to ensure all errors are handled correctly is to use TRY/CATCH

Without this, different errors can be statement, scope or batch aborting depending on settings such as ARITHxx, ANSI_WARNINGS and XACT_ABORT. This is demonstrated and discussed at ["Error Handling in SQL 2000"](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#statementbatch)

You can see the different (no SET options changed) with this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblPrueba (gbn int);
GO

BEGIN TRY

    begin transaction
        PRINT 'start'
        PRINT 1/0
        PRINT 'continue'
        drop table dbo.tblPrueba
        select * from dbo.tblPrueba
        PRINT 'finish'
    rollback transaction

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 rollback transaction
END CATCH
```

If I run this twice, I get this because the DROP is never executed

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
>   There is already an object named 'tblPrueba' in the database.

Comment: @PankajGarg: If you end up in a CATCH block, I'd Rollback. I also use SET XACT_ABORT ON which will rollback anyway

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I learn those that stop execution

**You can use exception handling**

---

```
Begin try
  begin transaction
    PRINT 'start'
    PRINT 1/0
    PRINT 'continue'
    create table #t
    ( 
       id int
    )
    drop table #t
    select * from #t
    PRINT 'finish'
  rollback transaction
End Try

Begin Catch
   if( XACT_STATE() == 1)
     Rollback Tran
End Catch
```

---

**You can use `Set XACT_ABORT ON` like below.**

```
Set XACT_ABORT ON
begin transaction
    PRINT 'start'
    PRINT 1/0
    PRINT 'continue'
    create table #t
    ( 
       id int
    )
    drop table #t
    select * from #t
    PRINT 'finish'
rollback transaction
```